# Install Alpine Linux on Raspberry Pi 2 struggle with root password

Tags: raspberry-pi, alpine-linux

I am installing Alpine Linux on my Raspberry Pi 2B according to 
https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi. after follow the instruction to the letter I can finally boot it up but I can not log in with the password I entered during the step setup-alpine command requires. I try several time with easy password that the setup-alpine script complain it is a weak password also with password that do not have any message complained by the setup script or just hit enter to leave the password undefined. all options that I did rendered the system useless after reboot there is no way to log on to the system with root user. I try to register a user in their community bulletin but they are closed to new registration of new user so I have to come here for help. any body have experience installing it on raspberry pi 2 please advice. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way out on this matter after a 2 days of frustration. root user can not log on because I do setup in headless mode which I do not attached the raspberry pi to a monitor and keyboard and do it through ssh. the configuration of ssh do not allow root log on remotely (I guess) so I add another user then log on with that user through ssh instead and I can log on without issue. I guess another method would edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config add a line PermitRootLogin yes to allow root login before reboot the system

Comment: I feel your pain.  When working with RPi, I have found it necessary to always experiment with a LCD and keyboard and only go headless when I have it all debugged. I have been caught as you have several times before adopting this revised workflow.